# Have emoji working in sphinx latexpdf xelatex generated content, titles and code

Tags: fonts, python-sphinx, emoji, truetype, xelatex

How to have emojis in sphinx latexpdf xelatex generated for:

- content ? OK
- titles  ? **KO**
- code   ?  **KO**

Below a sphinx to illustrate emoji in latexpdf:

```
$ sphinx-quickstart --no-batchfile --no-sep -p test_emoj -l en -a me -v 1.0 -q
$ cd test_emoj; tree
├── _build
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
├── Makefile
├── NotoColorEmoji.ttf
├── _static
└── _templates
```

add some content:

```
$ vim index.rst
$ cat index.rst 
=========
test_emoj
=========

Hello space 
==============

Space  and hammer .

.. code::

  ✔ app 8 layers [⣿⣿⣿]  Pulled
$
```

Set latex_engine and article xelatex:

```
echo "latex_engine ='xelatex'"  >> conf.py
echo "latex_theme='howto'"  >> conf.py
```

HTML emoji are ok

```
$ make html 
...
$
```

[image: HTML emoji are ok]

latexpdf with `xelatex` engine have **no emoji**:

```
$ make latexpdf 
...
$ evince _build/latex/test_emoj.pdf
```

[image: no emoji]

with `setmainfont` get get some emoji (B&W and only in content):

```
$ echo 'latex_elements = {"preamble": r"\setmainfont{Symbola}"}' >> conf.py
$ make latexpdf 
...
$ evince _build/latex/test_emoj.pdf
```

[image: with Symbola B&W emoji but not on title and code]

The corresponding latex code expose that font for `section` does not know about emoji, neither font define for `sphinxVerbatim`::

```
$ vim _build/latex/test_emoj.tex
...
\section{Hello space }
\label{\detokenize{index:hello-space}}
\sphinxAtStartPar
Space , hammer  and ⣿

\begin{sphinxVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\(\pmb{\checkmark}\) app 8 layers [⣿⣿⣿]  Pulled
\end{sphinxVerbatim}
...
```

The latex log file expose that in `code::` latex look for emoji in `FreeMono.otf` and in title latex look for emoji in `FreeSansBold.otf`:

```
$ grep '^Missi' _build/latex/test_emoj.log 
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F680) in font [FreeSansBold.otf]/OT:script
Missing character: There is no ⣿ (U+28FF) in font [FreeMono.otf]/OT:script=latn
Missing character: There is no ⣿ (U+28FF) in font [FreeMono.otf]/OT:script=latn
Missing character: There is no ⣿ (U+28FF) in font [FreeMono.otf]/OT:script=latn
$
```

To see which one of my fonts has the `⣿`.

```
$ java -jar /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/albatross/albatross.jar --detailed ⣿
```

On my unbuntu 22.04 the below fonts have the ⣿ character:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansSymbols2-Regular.ttf
```

Beyond the

> "Have emoji working in sphinx latexpdf xelatex generated content,
> titles and code"

question, I wonder why:

- how `\setmainfont` can have both `Symbola` and `FreeSerif` values in tex file, I expect to have only one mainfont, idealy to define `Symbola` as a fall back font in case characters are not found in the `FreeSerif` "mainfont":

  ```
    $ grep setmainfont _build/latex/test_emoj.tex 
    \setmainfont{FreeSerif}[
    \setmainfont{Symbola}
    $
  ```
- is there a way to have color emoji ?

Note: [Sphinx doc to configure latex](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html), here [so#497403](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497403/how-to-use-noto-color-emoji-with-lualatex) they talk about Noto Color Emoji but nothing on having emojis in title and code.